# Retrofit Coroutine Status Code 205 Body Null

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I'm having difficulty on getting the response data from server.

I have a validation scenario that server throws an error if a user already exist,
somehow someway, the api developer decided to use 205 as status code instead of usual 200.

The problem is everytime I'm calling the API, the body() and errorBody() returns null
As suggested, I used the Response to get the response.

isSuccessful() is returning true, I can see on my logcat the raw Json response from server
but return both null on body() and errorBody(), any idea what seems to be the error here?

Thanks In Advance.

```
override suspend fun safeRegisterAccount(registerBody: RegisterBody): LiveData<out Wrapper<RegisterResponse>?> {
        val result = MutableLiveData<Wrapper<RegisterResponse>>()
        try {
            val account = networkService.safeRegister(registerBody)
            val wrapper = Wrapper<Token>()  
            wrapper.objectData = account.body()?.objectData
            wrapper.status = account.code()
            result.postValue(wrapper)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            plantLog(ex.message)
        }

        return result
    }
```

Comment: Response codes 200..299 is success. So it should be success anyways. Can you show the code where you are fetching the response and checking `isSuccessful` and `body()`?.

Comment: @Antonio sure ill update the post.

Comment: Did you check if any exceptions are caught?

Comment: if did not go through exception. It went normally same as 200 status

Comment: So your live data is getting observed but the objectData is null?

Comment: yes correct and both errorBody and body is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrofit skips the converter if the status code is 204 or 205.

You can try adding an OkHttp Interceptor which would convert the server's 205 code to 200 before Retrofit works on it.

Like this:

```
class BodyInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())

        if (response.code == 204 || response.code == 205) {
            return response
                .newBuilder()
                .code(200)
                .body(response.body)
                .build()
        } else {
            return response
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Life saver mate ! Let me try this one thanks for help !